# Separate or merged indices for index.yaml with GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

I do queries like this with Python GAE:

```
a1 = Activity.query().filter(Activity.first=='foo').order(-Activity.date)
a2 = Activity.query().filter(Activity.second=='bar').order(-Activity.date)
```

Am I better off with two separate indices:

```
indexes:

- kind: Activity
  properties:
  - name: first
  - name: date
    direction: desc

- kind: Activity
  properties:
  - name: second
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

Or with a single index that covers both:

```
indexes:

- kind: Activity
  properties:
  - name: first
  - name: second
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

I suspect the former is better but wanted to check.

=====

To the person who voted to close as "opinion based", the two options above will change the index size and possibly also the speed of responding to queries.  Definitely not opinion based.  There is a right answer.

Comment: Don't know the correct answer but what about just running your queries on dev server with datastore emulator. In that scenario, the index will automatically be created and I assume it would create the most efficient one

Comment: They are created when the query is done so separate indices are created.  That doesn't confirm that separate is better though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option will provide you with an index that directly answers your query, so it will scale better, but does have a higher write cost (2 index entries, instead of 1).

The second will write out fewer index entries (1), but both queries will need to skip over any index entries. Also, the service isn't required to allow the second query with the index provided.  My tests show that the second query is currently rejected with an index like your second one.

Comment: Thanks Jim.  So it looks like I have to do the first option.